# Check a List<List<int>[]> contains a value using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a `List<List<int>[]>` containing lists items e.g

```
List<int> a= new List<int>(){ 2, 2, 3, 4, 5};
List<int> b= new List<int>() { 2, 2, 2, 6 };
List<List<int>[]> c = new List<List<int>[]>();
c.Add(new[]{a,b});
```

I want to check if any of the arrays contained in c have 2 as a value . This is more or less a true or false answer.

So far I can check if a or b contains 2 using the Linq code

```
var result = a.Any(p=> p==2); // this outputs 2
```

extending this to the c

```
var result=c.Any(p=> p.Select(value => value.Contains(2)).First());
```

// the above code p=> p.Select(value => value.Contains(2)) returns an Enumerable and I take the first one. I'm not positive this is the right way to go about this problem using linq.
Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `c.Any(x => x.Any(y => y.Any(z => z==2)))`

Comment: If you have a list of lists, I suppose the brackets are redundant. Shouldn't be List<List<int>>  instead?

Comment: Good spot on- I made an error , will make  amends.

Comment: >List of arrays of lists of int ... the horror

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know how to search in a single list, you should be able to search in list of lists exactly the same way. Just flatten it with [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) and use the same criteria.

For your case, if this is for single list:

```
var result = a.Any(p => p == 2);
```

then for list of lists it would be:

```
var result = c.SelectMany(x => x).Any(p => p == 2);
```

and similar for third level as in your example:

```
var result = c.SelectMany(x => x).SelectMany(x => x).Any(p => p == 2);
```

Comment: I think `SelectMany` expresses the idea "any item in 2d array irrespective of position" the best.

Answer (score 2):

I love PetSerAl's any any any answer but a tiny change

```
c.Any(x => x.Any(y => y.Contains(2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

you need something like this:

```
c.Where(i=>i.Any(x=>x.Contains(2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> a = new List<int>() { 2, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> b = new List<int>() { 2, 2, 2, 6 };

List<List<int>[]> c = new List<List<int>[]>();
c.Add(new[] { a, b });

//Lambda
bool IsValueExists = c.Any(i => i != null && i.Any(i1 => i1.Any(i2=>i2 == 2)));
//OR
//Linq
bool IsValueExists = (from i in c
                      from i1 in i
                      from i2 in i1
                      where i2 == 2
                      select i2).Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c.SelectMany(inner=>inner.SelectMany (i =>i )).Contains(2).Dump();
```